# The program takes the first digit of the [small] value and needs the [big] value to start with the same or a higher digit

Tags: python, validation

The program asks the user for a small and a big number. It counts from the small number to the big number, then prints the total of all the numbers.
For example, if the small = 4 and the big = 29, then it would ask for a bigger number. Anything less than 40 would ask for a bigger number. So if you put 9 for the small number then anything lower than 90 wouldn't work.

```
valid = False
validation = False
total = 0
# Validates the small number
while not valid:
    small = input('Enter a small number: ')
    if small.isnumeric():
        # int(small)
        valid = True
    else:
        print('Not a valid input. Please enter a bigger whole number.')
# Validates the big number
while not validation:
    big = input('Enter a big number: ')
    if big.isnumeric() and big >= small:
        # int(big)
        validation = True
    else:
        print('Not a valid input. Please enter a whole number.')
for number in range(int(small), int(big) + 1):
    print(number)
    total += number
print("")
print(f'The grand total of all the numbers is: {total:,d}.')
```

I tried the comments in the if statements `int(small)`], to change the values into numbers before the for loop so I wouldn't need to put `int(small/big)` in the for loop. That crashed the program because it didn't convert them into numbers, so the for loop couldn't run. I also had the `big>small` inside the `big.isdigit()`, and put them together, though I'm not sure if that is important information.

Comment: If you want to convert a string value to int, the best thing to do is pass the string to the int() function and handle any possible exception

Comment: Please think carefully about the logic of the code. **Which happens first** - converting the inputs to integer, or comparing them? Therefore, what will their types be during the comparison? "I tried the comments in the if statements int(small)], to change the values into numbers before the for loop" - these lines have **no lasting effect**; they create a **new value** that is immediately thrown away. Please see the linked duplicate in order to understand how to do it properly.

Comment: Ignore this, I figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

Convert your inputs to `int` right after they are valid and use `break` to stop the loops.

```
valid = False
validation = False
total = 0
# Validates the small number
while 1:
    small = input('Enter a small number: ')
    if small.isnumeric():
        small = int(small)
        break
    else:
        print('Not a valid input. Please enter a bigger whole number.')
# Validates the big number
while 1:
    big = input('Enter a big number: ')
    if big.isnumeric():
        big = int(big)
        if big >= small:
            break
    else:
        print('Not a valid input. Please enter a whole number.')
for number in range(small, big + 1):
    print(number)
    total += number
print("")
print(f'The grand total of all the numbers is: {total:,d}.')
```

Out:

```
Enter a small number: 2
Enter a big number: 20
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

The grand total of all the numbers is: 209.
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the program only takes large number that its first digit is larger than the first digit of small number provided is that both `big` and `small` are string.

When you are using the `>` operator of strings it first comparing the values in position 0, then in position 1...

If you want the program to check if the second number is larger than the first one you should first convert them to `int`.

You can change your if to be like that
 `if big.isnumeric() and int(big) >= int(small):` and then it should work.

---

I would recommend you to create a function for receiving the numbers:

```
def get_a_number(text):
    while True:
        num = input(text)
        if num.isnumeric():
            return int(num)
        else:
            print('Not a valid input. Please enter a bigger whole number.')
            
small = get_a_number("Enter a small number: ")
big = small-1
while big < small:
    big = get_a_number("Enter a big number: ")
```

---

You can also print like this:

```
lst = list(range(small, big+1))
print(*lst, sep='\n')
print(f'The grand total of all the numbers is: {sum(lst)}.')
```